# Xcode: Organizer Throws Multiple CFBundleShortVersionString Error

Tags: xcode

Im trying to upload a new build of my app. But the organiser throws a lot of error saying about version string. I think the versions string that the organiser is saying are the version in the plist of my external framework. How to resolve this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It is a bug. Fixed in Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

It says very clearly,please  change your CFBundleShortVersionString over 4.2.3,some like 4.2.4 etc.

Comment: It is a single error thrown by itunes. Its a list. My app has 5.0 version number.